# Testing Angular Factory with Jasmine is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine. I've written a simple code to execute in JS Fiddle which is working perfectly fine. But, when I include jasmine code, its not working. Am I missing anything here?

```
var app = angular.module('sortModule', [])
app.factory('sortFactory', function(){
    var sortedColors = []
var shouldPush = true;
return {
    sortColors: function(colorsArray){
        var colorsOrder = [{color:'green'},{color:'yellow'},{color:'blue'},{color:'red'}]      
      for(color in colorsOrder) {
        for(objColor in colorsArray)     {
            shouldPush = colorsOrder[color].color === colorsArray[objColor].color ? true : false
          if(shouldPush) {sortedColors.push(colorsArray[objColor]);} 
        }
      }
      return sortedColors;
    }
}               
});
app.controller('sortController', function($scope,sortFactory){    
    $scope.colorsArray = [{id: '1',color: 'red',code : '#ff0000'},{id: '2',color: 'blue',code : '#0000ff'},{id: '3',color: 'red',code : '#ff0000'},{id: '4',color: 'yellow',code : '#ffff00'},{id: '5',color: 'green',code : '#00ff00'}];
    $scope.sortedColors = sortFactory.sortColors($scope.colorsArray) 
});

describe('colors', function () {
     beforeEach(module('sortModule'));
    it('can get the actual sorted ordered colors list', inject(function(sortFactory) {
    expect(sortFactory).toBeDefined();
}));    
});

var NOT_IMPLEMENTED = undefined;

// load jasmine htmlReporter
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
  env.execute();
}());
```

Actual working fiddle without Jasmine
    http://jsfiddle.net/SyedNizamChennai/kjuemhua/15/

New fiddle when Jasmine is included

```
https://jsfiddle.net/SyedNizamChennai/5d4f0hdL/3/
```

Answer (score 0):

Test code contains `module` function

```
beforeEach(module('sortModule'));
```

This is function from [ngMock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) module, you need include it as external resource.

https://jsfiddle.net/SyedNizamChennai/5d4f0hdL/3/

EDIT:

working example is here: 
http://jsbin.com/lenogujesi/1/edit?html,output

(i used jsbin to better show dependencies and their order)

some notes:

- if is jasmine loaded, angular mock expose function mock and others as global (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock#function), otherwise function is undefined
- angular and angular mock should have same version

Comment: What should I do for the fix? Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module sortModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'sortModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Oh. Just including as external resource. But, I didn't find any CDN resource for it.

Comment: for example here http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-mocks.js Just note that, version of angular and angular-mock should be same. You can change number of version in url

Comment: Thats having the same issue again. Please check the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/SyedNizamChennai/5d4f0hdL/4/